# Is the ram mentioned in Leviticus 16 the same as the one in Numbers 29?

Tags: law, numbers, leviticus, sacrifice

Leviticus 16:3 NASB

> Aaron shall enter the Holy Place with this: with a [d]bull as a [e]sin offering and ***a ram*** as a burnt offering.

Numbers 29:2 NASB

> And you shall offer a burnt offering as a soothing aroma to the Lord: one [a]bull, ***one ram***, and seven male lambs one year old without defect

Is the ram mentioned in the above texts one and the same?

Answer (score 1):

The OP question actually asks about two different ceremonies 10 days apart.

1. **Feast of Trumpets, Num 29:1-6**

This was to be held on the first day of the seventh month with a bull and a ram

2. **Day of Atonement, Num 29:7-11, Lev 16**

This was to be held in the 10th day of the seventh month with the offering of a bull and a ram plus tow goats (as per Lev 16)

Thus, the offerings on each festival were seperate.